# Missing headers for kernel in bzImage loaded on qemu

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, header-files, kernel-module, qemu

I am trying to compile a kernel module of kernel version 3.2.0 on a linux kernel bzImage loaded on a qemu emulator, however I am getting the following error:
`/lib/modules/3.2.0/build no such file or directory`. I tried to look up solutions over the net but nothing specific related to solve this for a kernel image being loaded over qemu. The command I issue to load the bzImage on qemu is `qemu/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -kernel ../linuxkernel/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -hda ../../sid.ext2 -append "root=/dev/sda"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bzImage` only contain kernel's image, it doesn't contain files needed for build modules.

You should:

1. Find kernel headers(with some files built), corresponded to you kernel, and install them to directory, to which `/lib/modules/3.2.0/build` points.
2. Or build kernel from the sources by hands. In that case reference `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build` will point to your compiled source files automatically.

Comment: so basically you are saying that I should separately compile a kernel version 3.2.0 with the modules and then simply copy the contents of `/lib/modules/3.2.0/build` to the same location on my qemu disk image ?

Comment: You should compile precisely same kernel sources with precisely same configuration as one in `bzImage`. Otherwise, your modules would work incorrectly. Because it is usually difficult to find same sources, you better find ready-made header files, corresponded to image you have.